# Fix link to go back to form or home page

Tags: php

I am a little lost, I am trying to place a link to go back to the "form" page or "home" page for every error message when user submit the form. As well when user succesfully submit the form, it gives link to go back to form page or home page. Basically I want a fix link return to form or home page. Thank you guys, please let me know what i could do or guide me.

This is my code so far for the process part:

```
<?php
//
//umask(0007)
//mkdir($newdir, 02770);
//$filename = "../../data/status.txt";


$errors = array();
$permissionsArray = (isset($_POST['permission']) ? $_POST['permission'] : null);

if (isset($_POST["statuscode"])) 
{
    $statusCode = $_POST["statuscode"];
    $patternCode = "/^S[0-9]{4}$/";
    if (preg_match($patternCode, $statusCode)) 
    {
        $ans = "";
        $length = strlen($statusCode);
        echo $statusCode . "<br />";
    }
}
else
{
    array_push($errors, "Please fill in Status Code as they are mandatory field");
}

if (isset ($_POST["status"])) 
{
    $status = $_POST["status"];
    $pattern = "/^[a-zA-Z0-9\s\.,!?]*$/";
    if (preg_match($pattern, $status)) 
    {
        echo $status . "<br />";
    }
}
else
{
    array_push($errors, "<b>Error:</b> Please fill in Status as they are mandatory field!");
}

if (isset ($_POST["share"])) 
{
    $shareButton = $_POST["share"];
    echo $shareButton . "<br />";
}
else
{
    //Not possible unless in exceptional circumstances
    array_push($errors, "Please choose a share");
}

if (!isset($_POST["date"])) 
{
    $date = date("d/m/y");
    echo $date . "<br />";
} else {
    $date = $_POST["date"];
} 

if (isset($permissionsArray)) 
{
    foreach($permissionsArray as $permission){
        echo $permission . "<br />";
    }
}


if(isset($statusCode, $status))
{
    if(empty($statusCode) || empty($status))
    {
    array_push($errors, "Please fill in the required part!");
    }
    if (0 === strlen($statusCode > 5 || $statusCode < 5)) 
    {
        array_push($errors, "<b>Error:</b> You characters length is either less or more than 5 characters<br/>");
    }
    if (0 === preg_match("/\S+/", $statusCode)) 
    {
        array_push($errors, "<b>Error:</b> You forgot to fill in Status Code!<br/>");
    }
    if (0 === preg_match("/\S+/", $status)) 
    {
        array_push($errors, "<b>Error:</b> You forgot to fill in the Status! <br/>");
    }
    if (0 === preg_match($patternCode, $statusCode)) 
    {
        array_push($errors, "<b>Error:</b> please make sure that the first letter in Status Code is uppercase 'S' following by 4 numbers. <br/>");
    }
    if (0 === preg_match($pattern, $status)) 
    {
        array_push($errors, "<b>Error:</b> Please make sure to avoid symbols other than \",.?!\" <br/>");
    }
}

if (isset($errors)) 
{
    foreach ($errors as $error) 
    {
        echo '<strong>', $error, '</strong>';
    }
}




?>
```

Comment: Add this error message code right before the form printing code.

Comment: Don't make them go back when there is an error. Have the form submit to it's self, validate it when there is post data, then display the errors above the form, with all the values from $_POST placed in their respective form fields. I get royally pissed off when forms work the way you're describing yours is. I lose the data I've entered (main issue) and there is an extra step in a form, which users generally dislike anyway. Just do it inline. Have an `if (!empty($_POST['some_field'])) { // validation code }` just above the form.

Answer (score 2):

You can use a link to invoke `history.go(-1)` in Javascript, which is actually the same as clicking the back button in your browser.

For example in PHP (your file) that would be: `echo "<a href=\"javascript:history.go(-1)\"> GO BACK </a>";`

**Edit:**

So strictly PHP? Try this then:

```
header('Location: ' . $_SERVER['HTTP_REFERER']);
```

Comment: Hi 1BJK903, I am trying to strictly do PHP, I can't do javascript :S

Comment: sorry to ask you a lot, but are there any other ways?

Comment: I want to go back to my phpstatusform.php

Answer (score 0):

Use this one

```
$ref = $_SERVER['HTTP_REFERER'];
header("Location:".$ref);
```

$_SERVER['HTTP_REFERER'] gives you the URL from where you are redirected.